# Docker in docker bindings not appearing in nested docker docker-py

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I have the following code

```py
print(listdir(path.abspath(path1)))

    container = client.containers.run(
        image.id,
        detach=True,
        command="bash entry_point.sh",
        volumes={
            path.abspath(path1): {'bind': "/config", 'mode': 'rw'},
            path.abspath(path2): {'bind': "/app", 'mode': 'rw'}
        },
        stderr=True,
```

When working locally this works as expected. However when this process is dockerized I get the following:

The print statement lists all the files in the folder, however these do not appear in the docker container.

Not sure what to try. I tried to change things in my DinD image, but that doesn't seem to help anything.